# Transform variable to final

Tags: java, declaration, final

Say I have a variable declared, and I want to declare it final. Is there a way to update the current variable to final, instead of declaring a new? I.e. something like

```
double respirationRate = 0;
// ... something that manipulates respirationRate
final respirationRate; // <--- I want to do this

activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // something with final version of respirationRate
    }
});
```

Comment: I suspect you may want something like the Builder pattern - create a mutable template, then instantiate an immutable object with said template. I'm not sure though - what's your use case here?

Comment: What's the thing you're trying to avoid by simply copying the value into a fresh (final) variable for the purposes of the thread to access?

Comment: I could think of a generic type that can be assigned another object exactly once. That would not be hard to program but it would be a runtime check only.

Answer (score 2):

The [Java specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) contains the exact definition of final variables. This definition states that "a variable can be declared to be final" and that "final variables may only be assigned to once". This means that - no. A final variable is a variable declared as final.

Asking for a variable that changes a couple of times and then becomes final would be like asking how one can become a virgin again after living promiscuitously for some time.

Comment: I was thinking of a final declaration like the variable is being put into retirement. My idea is that you can do a lot of stuff while your career is active, but once you're retired, you're retired. But I guess that's not the case with variables in Java :)

Comment: There are some good reasons to the model used in Java, I will amend my answer a bit later :)

Answer (score 0):

You can not change a variable which is already created to final.  You would have to create a new variable and make that final and equal to the variable you want to convert.

If you don't want to do it that way, you can make an array of what variable type you want and make the array have one index.  The index can be changed, but the array can not be reinitialized.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, as long as you make sure it is assigned a value once, either directly or in the constructor. You cannot redeclare a variable though, and the `final` keyword *is part of the declaration*.

So you can simply do:

```
final double respirationRate = 0;
```

Alternatively you could use a temporary variable - as suggested:

```
final double respirationRate;
... create double myTemp
respirationRate = myTemp;
```

this should work as long as you assign respirationDate exactly once. It won't work for method arguments though. Neither does it work for fields - after instantiation of the object they need to be assigned, you cannot change the values from a method. So you cannot lock a variable value at just any time.

---

You could think of a *runtime* construction to lock the setting of the value. You would make the instance of `OneTimeAssignable` itself `final` of course, and instantiate it immediately / in the constructor:

```
public final class OneTimeAssignable<T> {
    T t = null;

    public T get() {
        return t;
    }

    public void set(T t) throws IllegalStateException {
        if (this.t != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("Already assigned");
        }
        this.t = t;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final OneTimeAssignable<Double> d = new OneTimeAssignable<>();
        d.set(0.);
        try {
            d.set(1.);
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

currently it returns `null` if not assigned.

Answer (score 0):

You're not going to be able to modify a variable declaration after it's been declared. You can use the builder pattern to implement functionality where you have some prototypical mutable object defined, and use that object to instantiate an immutable object once you're done creating.

Here, I have a class `SomeData`, and the only way to get a hold of an instance of it is through it's builder.

```
class SomeData {
    public static class SomeDataBuilder {
        private int value; 

        public SomeDataBuilder SetValue(int value) {
            this.value = value;
            return this;
        }

        public int GetValue() {
            return value; 
        }

    }

    public final int value; 

    private SomeData(int value) {
        this.value = value; 
    }

    public static SomeData GetSomeData(SomeDataBuilder b) {
        return new SomeData(b.value); 
    }

    public static SomeData.SomeDataBuilder GetBuilder() {
        return new SomeData.SomeDataBuilder(); 
    }
}
```

and then later the use of `SomeData`:

```
SomeData.SomeDataBuilder builder = SomeData.GetBuilder();
builder.SetValue(10)
       .SetValue(42);
       // and other calls to modify builder

SomeData data = SomeData.GetSomeData(builder); 

System.out.println(data.value);
```